# Why "ls" is not colored after forkpty()

Tags: linux, fork, ls, pty

Why output of `ls` executed here is not colored?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pty.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv ) {
    termios termp; winsize winp;
    int amaster; char name[128];
    if (forkpty(&amaster, name, &termp, &winp) == 0) {
        system("ls"); // "ls --color" will work here!
        return 0;
    }
    wait(0);
    char buf[128]; int size;
    while (1) {
        size = read(amaster, buf, 127);
        if (size <= 0) break;
        buf[size] = 0;
        printf("%s", buf);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

According to `man` (and `ls.c` that I am inspecting) it should be colored if `isatty()` returns true. After `forkpty()` it must be true. Besides, `ls` **DOES** output in columnized mode in this example! Which means it feels it has `tty` as output.

Of course I do not want only `ls` to output color, but an arbitrary program to feel that it has real color enabled `tty` behind.

I just wrote a simple test:

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
    printf("%i%i%i%i%i\n", isatty(0), isatty(1), isatty(2), isatty(3), isatty(4));
}
```

and call it in a child part of `forkpty`, and it displays `11100`, which means `ls` should be colored!

OK, as it seems the fact that `ls` produces no color output has nothing to do with `forkpty()`. It is just not color enabled by default. But now, maybe that's another question, why it is not color if it just checks `isatty()`?

Comment: I can't compile your example. I'm simply doing "gcc t.c" and it complains about termios not existing.

Comment: Could it be environment variables?

Comment: @w00t `termios` should be `struct termios`, `winsize` should be `struct winsize`; and link with `-lutil`.

Comment: Is `ls` an alias such as `ls --color` in your shell?

Comment: w00t, to compile type g++, because I was lazy to conform to C

Comment: @leeduhem, you are right, ls is alias, but still, man says isatty() should matter some how

Comment: By default, my `ls` (coreutils 8.13) does not use color in its output. Does your `ls` use color by default? For example, if you run `ls` by the absolute path (`/bin/ls` in my case) in your interactive shell, does it use color?

Comment: @leeduhem, /bin/ls is not colored on my system in normal xterm

Comment: Well, in this case, I guess what you got (`ls` does not use color) is normal, because even in the interactive shell which color can be used, `ls` also does not use color by default.

Comment: @exebook What exactly does your man page say ? The only mention of tty in my manpage is when you use the `--color=auto` flag. If you run `system("ls")` , there will be no colors, since you do not tell it to use colors. If you run `ls` in a shell, whose alias is `ls --color=tty` , you get colors, since `ls --color=tty` gets executed instead of just `ls`

Comment: `print_with_color = (i == color_always || (i == color_if_tty && isatty (STDOUT_FILENO)));` this is `ls.c:1610` you are right, it just should not be colored